# Trackpad button is unavailable when creating signature in Preview

Tags: preview, trackpad, signature

When I try to create a signature, Camera and iPhone are available to create a signature, but the Trackpad button is not active.

[image: Greyed out trackpad button]

How can I get my trackpad to work as a caputure device?

Comment: Preview Version 11.0 (1044.2)

Comment: tbh, I'd just use the camera - at least it will look like your actual signature. The others rarely do.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Are you using a MacBook? Do you have a Trackpad connected to your Mac?

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue. You are maybe using a BT trackpad which isn't connected with you Mac. ;) Also, did you really take this screenshot? From the two buttons at the top-right of the picture, it seems to be taken from Google or some other search engine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with the native trackpad. I force quitted preview and after re-opening a document in preview it started working again. I hope this works for you or anyone else encountering the problem.